# Stripping string values at different positions

Tags: python, pandas, strip

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['AB_123_CD','EF_123CD','XY_Z'],'Y':[1,2,3]})
           X  Y
0  AB_123_CD  1
1   EF_123CD  2
2       XY_Z  3
```

I want to use strip method to get rid of the first prefix such that I get

```
        X  Y
0  123_CD  1
1   123CD  2
2       Z  3
```

I tried doing: `df.X.str.split('_').str[-1].str.strip()` but since the positions of `_`'s are different it returns different result to the one desired above. I wonder how can I address this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you can split once (`n=1`) from the left and keep the second one (`str[1]`):

```
df.X = df.X.str.split("_", n=1).str[1]
```

to get

```
>>> df

        X  Y
0  123_CD  1
1   123CD  2
2       Z  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
df["X"] = df["X"].apply(lambda x: x[x.find("_")+1:])
>>> df 
        X  Y
0  123_CD  1
1   123CD  2
2       Z  3
```

This keeps the entire string after the first occurence of `_`

Answer (score 1):

The following code could do the job:

```
df['X'] = df.X.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is very close. With some minor changes, it should work:

```
df.X.str.split('_').str[1:].str.join('_')

0    123_CD
1     123CD
2         Z
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define maxsplit in the str.split() function. It sounds like you just want to split with maxsplit 1 and take the last element:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_',1)[-1])
```